# How to provide auto-increment for every time onPress function called in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native, increment, auto-increment

I am working on this React Native project for self-learning purposes. Every time I press the submit button, I would like to id value to auto-increase. For example, if the latest submitted item's id was 7, I want new ID to be 8. I thought if I can find the highest value in my ID row, then I can add 1 to it and make a new id for the new submitted item. I looked around and came up with a solution like this:

```
  handleAddToList = () => {
    let items = [...this.state.items];
    let lastId = Math.max.apply(null, items.id);
    let newId = lastId + 1;

    items.filter(i => i.title == this.state.text).length === 1
      ? alert("This item is on the list already.")
      : items.push({
          id: newId,
          title: this.state.text,
          found: 0,
          value: 0,
          icon: "delete"
        });
   this.setState({ items: items });
  };
```

And here is my little form that I submit the text:

```
<Input
 placeholder="Start typing"
 label={"Your next shop list item..."}
 onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
/>
<Button title="Add to list" onPress={() => this.handleAddToList()} />
```

My function actually adds the item for the first time, but when I add a new item, then I get this warning:

```
Warning: Encountered with two children with the same key, '"-infinity"'.
```

And this is how I list my items:

```
<ListItem
 key={l.id}
 title={l.title}
 rightIcon={{ name: l.icon, color: "#cc0033" }}
 bottomDivider={true}
/>
```

That means that lastId and newId parts of my code does not work properly.

I would appreciate any help on how I can make my ID's increase with every new submitted item.

Comment: how are you rendering `<ListItem />` ?

Comment: I don't understand your question? I added my <ListItem /> up there. That's in a map function of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's about your `lastId` variable. which is fixable like this:

```
Math.max.apply(null, items.map(item => item.id))
```

Comment: Second variable should have been an array, of course. This solved my problem like a wizard. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have found the answer above already. In any case, if you wanted to avoid keeping track of your local IDs you can render your items is using the index as a key and avoid handling/creating unique IDs in the front end.

```
{
  this.state.item.map((item, index) => (
    <ListItem 
      key={index} 
      title={item.title} 
      rightIcon={{ name: item.icon, color: "#cc0033" }} 
      bottomDivider={true} 
    />
  )
}
```

Note: A reason why you would like to *not* create IDs locally, is because most times unique IDs already come from the backend.

Comment: When you are fetching the items, this works. But how am I going to add (push) items to my array in state with automatic index value? That was my original question. If you can check my handleAddToList() function also, I would deeply appreciate it.

Comment: Well, I assume you are saving these IDs in localstorage or something like that. on `componentWillMount()` you should run a function to check your storage and find the max ID as you do already, then update the state with this max ID, finally, in your `handleAddToList` just read the state and increment by one then update the state.  That said, I would still recommend not using IDs, if you need add to the list just push to the array without the ID logic, if you need to delete an item, render `<ListItem>` with an "onClick" even that more or less looks like `() => this.handleDeleteThis(index)`

Comment: I was searching about index after your initial answer then I found an article saying index is not working well if you are filtering the list items in the front end or delete and re add stuff to your array. That article was saying creating your own IDs in the front end actually works better. That kind of got into my head and that’s why I decided to keep my own version instead of using index.

Comment: Here is the link to the article: https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: Very interesting! I personally haven't find any issues yet using the technique I explained, of course, is merely another technique, use what suits you better!